# Scripts on rc0.d doesn't run on amazon linux as network terminates before that

Tags: linux, curl, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

Script on rc0.d (K01) doesn't run on amazon linux (Ec2 Amazon AMI) as network terminates before that.

I have written a script that posts on external API but when i try to run it as shutdown script it doesn't work as network gets terminated before this script.

for clarification my script is on order K01 and the error i get is as below

when i use hostname on script
curl: (6) Could not resolve host: xyz.abc.com

when i use ip on script
curl: (7) Failed to connect to some ip: Network is unreachable